# Server issue when searching Oracle database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timeout

I have a JEE application searching a large Oracle databse for data. The application uses JDBC to query the database.

The issue I am having is that the results page is unable to be displayed. I get the following error:

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

This happens after 60 seconds. When I run the sql query manually using a SQL client, the results return in 3 seconds.

I have checked the logs and there are no exceptions that I can see.

Do any of you know the best way to find what is causing the connection to be reset? If I break my search date range into 2, and search both ranges individually, both return results. So it seems that it's the larger result set causing the issue.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue. The large sql query that I suspected to be the issue is not at fault, at least from my debugging. I stepped through the code and the client was able to retrieve the 5000 rows. 

I think the issue arises when the 5000 records are iterated, formatted and displayed onscreen. I think this is when the connection is reset. What I don't get is why.. Surely the connection to the server is stopped at this stage because I now have put my 5000 records into a Java list. I'm just iterating this list.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right about the larger result set. Often when running a query from a SQL client, you'll get the first set of records right away.  If you page down to force pull of all records, then it bogs down.  Perhaps your hitting the same issue with JDBC client where it takes more than 60 sec to get all the rows.  I've not done JDBC in a while, but can you get it to stream the result set?

Regards,
Roger
All views are mine ...